# cd command is not working in Apache with wwwrun user

Tags: ruby, apache, cgi

I am using Apache server on suse 14 and want to run a shell commands using ruby with CGI.

I have configured the ruby file and listen to a particular server and it is accessible via `http://servername:8182/rubyfile.rb`. The file is stored in `/var/wwww/html`.Unfortunately I am not able to run the shell command.

When I try to run the command as `wwwrun` user for eg- `sudo -u wwwrun "cd \opt\yard"`
I am getting the following error-

> sudo: cd \opt\yard: command not found

I have given permission to the contents of the folder

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 wwwrun root 4096 Mar  9 10:14 gems
drwxr-xr-x 3 wwwrun root 4096 Mar 14 11:53 payload-test    
drwxr-xr-x 3 wwwrun root 4096 Mar 11 13:50 test
```

**Observation**
If I try to run `sudo -u wwwrun "pwd && git status"` it is showing correct results.

Any help will be appreciated. **Kindly comment if there any query. Please do not down vote.**

Thanks for your help and understanding.

Comment: You have backslashes in your command (instead of slashes).

Comment: Sorry did not worked. Still the same error.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Downvoting is a tool used when people feel you haven't put enough effort or research into your question, or when the question isn't of value to others. Telling people to not down vote a question won't do any good, instead, make sure your question is good. I'd recommend reading "[ask]", including all the links at the bottom of that page. Keep in mind we're helping write a programming problem reference book, not having a discussion.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `cd` is not a regular command, so it behaves differently with `sudo`. Try to put `cd` before the `sudo`, e.g.:

```
cd /opt/yard && sudo -u wwwrun ...
```

Comment: But I want to run the multi line batch command for that I am testing it So I donot think so it will help.

Comment: I think you will need to prepend the `cd` and the `sudo` to each line, otherwise it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo` is correct: `cd` is not a command, it is a shell builtin, therefore the `cd` cannot be found, since it doesn't exist. (It's obviously impossible for `cd` to be a command, since it manipulates the parent's environment which commands cannot do.)

You need to invoke `cd` as a shell builtin. How you do that, depends on your shell. For [POSIX `sh`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sh.html), it goes something like this:

```
sudo -u wwwrun 'sh -c "cd /opt/yard"'
```